# Correctly aligning image captions

Tags: html, css, image, layout, caption

How can I achieve a layout like this?

[image]

Right now I'm using this HTML:

```
<div class="image">
  <img>
  <div class="caption">
    Caption Text
  </div>
</div>
```

And this CSS:

```
.image {
  background-color: #2A2A2A;
}

img {
  max-width: 590px;
}
```

But the `.image` box is too big (since it expands to fit its parent):

[image]

Comment: Can you show the markup and corresponding CSS rules?

Comment: If you can use JavaScript then refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839248/inline-image-and-caption-in-article-conform-captions-width-to-images-width.

Answer (score 2):

The key is to *not* set a width for the `img` element, or the parent container. If the parent, `.image` is simply floated or in any other way adapted so that it shrinks to the size of its contents, this should work.

I used `float` to achieve the shrink-wrap aspect, but `position: absolute;` would do the same, as would `display: inline-block;`.

There's a demo over at [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/azuca4/), which uses some jQuery to swap the images around, but it does nothing to the width of any elements. The CSS is reproduced below:

```
  .image {
    float: left;    // for the shrink wrap
    padding: 1em;   // To achieve the bordered effect
    background-color: #666;  // just for contrast
    -moz-border-radius: 2em;  // for that web 2.0 goodness...
    -webkit-border-radius: 2em;
    border-radius: 2em;
  }
  .image img {
    -moz-border-radius: 2em;    // no width, anywhere. Presumably width: auto, would  
    -webkit-border-radius: 2em; // work, but that's redundant, since it's the default
    border-radius: 2em;
  }
  .image img + .caption {
    width: 100%;              // forcing the .caption to take up 100% of the width
    background-color: #ffa;   // of its parent, except for the padding, so that it's
  }                           // the same width as the image above.
```

Comment: I dont think this quite works (although I have not tested it - I am about to). I have posted another answer with some extra code.

Comment: @ClarkeyBoy, the diagram in the question makes mention of *aligning* the caption with the image's sides, it doesn't say anything about the image appearing *over* the image itself. Or have I gone blind? ...it's been a long day, this *is*, sadly, quite possible.

Comment: I was correct - this method makes the caption appear below the image. Also if you have the image in from the left, the caption appears all the way along (100% of the page width). If you look at the first example, with the question "How can I achieve a layout like this?" just above it, the image has the caption at the bottom left, about 5 pixels inside the border. The border is dark grey, about 15px with a radius of 10px. I have achieved this in my second answer (couldnt have done it without this answer though).

Comment: be wary though: the display: inline-block; is not fully supported by IE6 (http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html), furthermore, IE 6-7 accept this value only on elements with a natural display: inline.
Also, using absolute positioning in order to fit the box to its contents, while achieving your main goal, also removes the element from the document flow, possibly causing you more trouble than worth..

Answer (score 1):

As @Kyle said, block elements adjust their width to fit their parent's.
Setting a block element as inline though, is not the correct approach: what you need to do, is to set the .image div as a floating element, thus achieving a similar result, while keeping the features of a block element. The css to do the trick should be:

```
.image {
  float: left;
  display: inline; /* needed to fix the (IE <= 6) "3 pixels out of nowhere bug" */
  /* whatever code you may find appropriate in order to render the rounded border */
}
.image .caption {
  clear: left;
}
```

I left to you any further style improvement you may feel needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the width of the `.image` box to the same width as the image, then apply padding to the `.image` box, you will get the border you are looking for because when you specify width, padding gets added to it.

So basically, you would need the following CSS:

```
.image {
    padding: 10px;
    width: 300px; /* assuming the picture is 300px */
}
```

Comment: But I don't know the width of the image ahead of time. I.e., I want the `.image` boxes to be able to hold images of all different widths

Answer (score 0):

Since divs are block-level elements, they expand to fit their parent.

It may not be the best solution, but if you don't know the size of the image ahead of time, you could do the below:

```
.image
{  
    padding: 10px;
    max-width: 590px;  
    disply: inline;  
}

.caption
{  
    background-color: #2A2A2A;
    disply: inline;  
}
```

The above will cause the img div to be rendered as an inline element which will shrink it to fit the content rather than its parent, and the `padding` will add the border.

Comment: But then I can't enclose the caption part in the `.image` box

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
.image {
    position: relative;
    width: 250px;
}
img {
    border: 15px solid #777777;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 100%;
}
.caption {
    border-left: 15px solid #777777;
    border-right: 15px solid #777777;
    border-bottom: 15px solid #777777;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

<div class="image">
    <img src="yourImage" height="150px" />
    <div class="caption">
        Caption TextCaption TextCaption TextCaption TextCaption Text
    </div>
</div>
```

Now the reason I have applied 3 borders to the caption div is because you do not know the width of the image without the border, but you do know the width of the border for the image. Applying the same border to the caption will give the caption the same width. Of course you will need to adjust the width of .image and the height of the img tag (this can be done through css), but the rest will be done for you. Also the caption div will resize for larger captions.

Regards,

Richard

PS this code has been tried and tested in Chrome - it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with another solution. I dont believe David Thomas' answer makes the caption appear within the image (by all means correct me if I am wrong), so try the code below (I have used a combination of my code and Davids).

```
.image {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    border: 15px solid #777777;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.caption {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 5px;
    left: 5px;
}
.image-container {
    position: relative;
}

<div class="image">
    <img src="/Images/header1.png" />
    <div class="caption">
        Caption Text Caption Text Caption Text Caption Text Caption Text Caption Text Caption Text Caption Text Caption Text Caption Text
    </div>
</div>
```